# Index was outside the bounds of the array using SQLITE and C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sqlite

I am somewhat aware of what is happening, but i'm not sure why it is happening in my code

```
        int d1 = db.Table<Sub>().Last().id;
        string text = db.Table<Sub>().Table.Columns.Count<TableMapping.Column>().ToString();
        int d2 = Convert.ToInt32(text);
        string[,] data = new string[d1, d2]; 
        foreach (var row in db.Table<Sub>())
        {
            for (int s = 0;s<d2;s++){
                data[row.id, s] = row.subject; // where error is detected
            }
        }
        int rowLength = data.GetLength(0);
        int colLength = data.GetLength(1);

        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
            {
                RunOnUiThread(() => { 
                    textview1.Append(string.Format("{0}", data[i,j]));
                });
            }
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                textview1.Append("\n");
            });
        }
        db.Close();
```

what i did was i dumped the data from a database into an array and then try to print each element in the 2d array.

Comment: As per my answer d1 is suspected to be d1+1, but anyway try catch the single problematic line and edit your question including at least the values of row.id, s, d1 and d2 immediately after the exc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible reason is because the row id is not zero based or there are jumps due to deleted rows and similar things, hence it can't be used as array row index. Replacing foreach with a for could be an idea to fix it.

Furthermore you're dimensioning the matrix with the id of the last row, that is not guaranteed to be the max id.

And even if it is and it is zero based, you need to add one to get the correct row dimension.

```
string[,] data = new string[d1+1, d2];
```

But a Count instead of Last would be more reasonable in the first place.

Comment: when rows got deleted, doesnt the next rows fill up the blank and get shifted up automatically? and isn't the first row always start on an index of 0?

Comment: When a row is deleted the id of the following one does not change

Comment: so how do you move it to fill the blank?

Comment: Back to the exception. You're dimensioning the matrix with the I'd of the last row and also this is not guaranteed to be the max id.

Comment: Finally, if you have N rows the last one will likely have id N-1 and that is not the correct dimension (N) to instanciate the matrix